# Cannot import inline-react-svg

Tags: svg, babeljs, next.js

I use Next.js + and design, in .babelrc I imported Ant Design, but now I can’t use SVG files, I imported inline-react-svg, but then I got the error `'Error :. plugins [0] [1] must be an object, false or undefined` without this import code, `{"libraryName": "antd","style": true}`everything works correctly

babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "inline-react-svg",
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "style": true
      },
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to import them via a function?

```
export const Logo = (props) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 180 27" {...props}>
    <path
      d="M112.2,9.6h-0.6v...z"
    />
  </svg>
);
```

then

```
import { Logo } from "../path/to/file"
```